# Replacing a string having double slash using sed or awk in linux

Tags: linux, string, shell, awk, sed

I wish to replace this

```html
<property name="sourceUrl" value="file://D:/Uploaded Files?move=../../backup&amp;include=.*.ok"/>
```

with this

```html
<property name="sourceUrl" value="file:///tmp/ETL-Files?move=../../backup&amp;include=.*.ok"/>
```

I am following an approach to first find the line number and then replace that line with the desired text, but that is not happening because of the `<` present at the start of the line.

```sh
 grep -n  ^<property name="sourceUrl" value= etl-job-context.xml
```

How can I solve this, or is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use sed.

```
sed 's~\(<property *name="sourceUrl" *value="\)[^?]*~\1file:///tmp/ETL-Files~g' file
```

Basic sed uses the Basic Regular Expression engine for matching. In BRE `\(..\)` is called a capturing group. So this would capture all chars which exist from the property tag up to the value parameter. And the remaining chars up to `?` were matched by `[^?]*`, which means to match any char but `?`, zero or more times.

Sed uses some special chars as delimiters. Here I used `~` because the replacement string contains `/` slashes. `\1` in the replacement refers to the chars which captured by group index 1. And the following chars will be appednded next to the captured chars. Note that the matched chars are automatically removed during replacement.

Comment: sorry my previous comment wasn't clear enough. I was hoping for an explanation of the command in smaller parts like why `~`is used and how the replacement is happening etc

Comment: thanks for the explanation , but if point 1 -  "matched chars are automatically removed during replacement." then why `<property *name="sourceUrl" *value=` is present after replacement ? point2 - use of `*value` why have u used `*` before `value`?

Comment: 1. what i mean by matched here means, matched but not captured. So the chars which are matched by `[^?]*` satisfies this condition. And also if you failed to mention `\1` in the replacement part, it also got removed. 2. see the char before *, it's space. space* matches zero or more spaces. Why i included here means, what if there are two spaces.

Comment: And the proper way of matching space is, `[[:blank:]]` or `[[:space:]]` for atleast one space, you need to add `\+` ie, `[[:blank:]]\+`